# Is there a way to parse a create view statement and generate links between its attributes and its source table's attributes in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I have an application where I have to display the link between view's attributes and its source table's attributes(for all views and tables in a database) in Snowflake.

similar to https://sqlflow.gudusoft.com/#/

Can someone help me with the logic for parsing the create view statements and generate the required links?

I have to cover all the scenarios including (simple view, materialized view, view with recursive statements ).

So far I am able to get result for these two cases by parsing the create view statement with regular expressions.

1. (view) (<view_name>) ((.*))( if not exists)? as - Simple View
2. (view) (<view_name>) as - Simple view with no field projections

(select) (.*) (from) - for getting the source's tables attributes.

I Know i am far from the result. Any help and suggestions would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the get_object_references() table function to get the table and view level dependencies. You'll have to do your own parsing for the columns. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_object_references.html

Comment: Thanks @GregPavlik i am getting the table and view link through get_object_references(), but need to work on the parser.